# macOS: Homebrew dylib formula all hit code-sign errors

Tags: macos, homebrew, code-signing

On macOS, I used to work with dynamic libraries installed via Homebrew with issues.

But with my latest setup:

- Mojave 10.14.6
- Xcode 11.2.1

I start getting code sign problems with the libs that used to work, such as protobuf.

Below is the console output when running a successfully built project:

```sh
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/myproj/_build/Debug/mam-host
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
    /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.11.1/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.11.1/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

What should I do?

Should I just

```sh
codesign -s "Mac Developer: me" /usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.22.dylib
```

Or do I have to build from source?

P.S. After running codesign command above I got the exact same error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally solved it.

You have two options:

- Option 1 **Disable checking on code-signing for libs**: `Project Settings > Signing & Capabilities > Hardened Runtime > Runtime Exceptions > Diable Library Validation`
- Option 2: **Code-sign libs using your code-signing identity**, e.g. `Apple Development: Your Name (10-char-ID)`

  - Remove public signature: `codesign --remove-signature /path/to/theirlib.dylib`
  - Sign with project signature: `codesign -s "Apple Development: Your Name (10-char-ID)"  /path/to/theirlib.dylib`