# Including brew installed library to XCode

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos

I am trying to create a Game with Raylib. I want to use XCode because I thought the Library Management would be as easy as with Visual Studio on Windows.

I installed the library with `brew install raylib`. Now I tried run this simple Project that I copied from the website of Raylib.

`main.c`:

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - keyboard input");

    Vector2 ballPosition = { (float)screenWidth/2, (float)screenHeight/2 };

    SetTargetFPS(60);               // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        // Update
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) ballPosition.x += 2.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)) ballPosition.x -= 2.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_UP)) ballPosition.y -= 2.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_DOWN)) ballPosition.y += 2.0f;
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

            DrawText("move the ball with arrow keys", 10, 10, 20, DARKGRAY);

            DrawCircleV(ballPosition, 50, MAROON);

        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

And I included the Search Path and Header Path as seen in the following picture:

[image]

The Code builds just fine, but no terminal session is started and no ball is drawn. You can see the in the picture also that the library is not loaded, but I don't understand why. I also made a screenshot of the libraries and frameworks I included:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214424/macos-homebrew-dylib-formula-all-hit-code-sign-errors)

I just removed the library validation form the project.