# How can I continue working on OpenGL with macOS Catalina 10.15.4?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, macos-catalina

I am trying to work with OpenGL on macOS Catalina 10.15.4 but there is a error;

GL/glew.h
GL/freeglut.h

file not found!

My code

```
//  main.cpp

#include"GL/glew.h" // error; 'GL/glew.h' file not found
#include"GL/freeglut.h" // error; 'GL/freeglut.h' file not found
#include<iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC

void display(void) { }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(500, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 350);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Merhaba Dunya");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

frameworks & libraries tab on Xcode;

[image: frameworks & libraries]

Build phases tab on Xcode;

[image: Build phases]

Header search path;

[image: header search path]

My friend has a lower version on his Mac and he can work on it. But my Mac up to date but I can't work?

I am working with OpenGL (c++)

Comment: You may need to add `/usr/local/include` to your "header search path". See the screenshots in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741236/including-brew-installed-library-to-xcode)

Comment: this settings stetted already, check post please, I added this setting image.

Comment: /usr/local. not /usr/locale. And shouldn't your university course have covered how to configure include and library paths?

Comment: Opps! This is my fault. Thanks for your help :) And my course show this all settings, but I missed the "e" key :) Sorry for your times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the path from;

`/usr/locale/include`

to;

`/usr/local/include`

thanks to [@Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje)

Answer (score 0):

These files come from third-party packages.
Install them with `brew install glew freeglut`.

Tell your friend to avoid freeglut, it is showing its age. Use SDL2 or GLFW instead.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion but this is our homework from our University. We need freeglut, GLEW. And I install them `brew install glew freeglut` but and I add it with following YouTube videos and docs. But it is not working, still.

Comment: "not working" is a useless diagnostic. How do you compile your code? What errors do you get?

Comment: I added images and details on post, please check it, and thank you for your helping

Answer (score 0):

Im using macOS Catalina v10.15.7 and I referred to two resources that helped me to set up freeglut, glew, glfw, and glm namely:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbBePBp_NbY&ab_channel=SticksStudios
and
http://macappstore.org/glm/

Basically, you can use homebrew to install all four libraries separately.

```
brew install freeglut
brew install glew
brew install glfw
brew install glm
```

For glm, you're pretty much done and can just add this header `#include <glm/glm.hpp>` above main.cpp file to start using it. As for glew and glfw, you may refer to the youtube video by Sticks Studios above for a better explanation of the configurations to do.