# macOS Catalina 10.15 xcode openGL not running window?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glut

I am working on a c++ project with openGL on Xcode, my code is build successful. But there is no display window?

My Xcode settings here;

[My first post - > Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524399/how-can-i-continue-working-on-opengl-with-macos-catalina-10-15-4?noredirect=1#comment108834167_61524399)

I need help, and my codes;

```
#include"GL/glew.h"
#include"GL/freeglut.h"
#include<iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC

void display(void) {
    
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(500, 200); //glut penceresinin ekran konumu
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 350); //glut penceresinin boyutları
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Merhaba Dunya");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

And Xcode print its terminal this error message;

```
freeglut (/Users/ismailyavuz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ornek-acjymofglobglnbdyttjfdcvjwya/Build/Products/Debug/ornek): failed to open display ''
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I research and find it. You need the XQuartz for running windows.

Visit this web site : https://www.xquartz.org

Download and install it.

It's working for me.

Answer (score -1):

It works if you install a windowing tool like XQuartz

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate answers.